# How to compute similarity between users given their ratings?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm going to use a hypothetical Netflix as an example. Let's pretend they have 1,000,000 users and allow users to rate shows from 1 to 5 stars, and there are 500 shows total. Let's also say the users don't have to rate each show, but most will get pretty close to rating all of them.

The objective is to be able to sort these users by similarity in postgres, such that any arbitrary user will be able to query for and paginate through the users most similar to them, ordered by this similarity.

I suppose I would either want to use the Euclidean distance or the Manhattan distance (faster due to no square root?) to compute this similarity number.

The problem is that this query is very expensive. If there are 1,000,000 users, to sort by similarity, you have to compare your 500 answers against all the other 999,999 users. That's around `999,999 * 500 = 499,999,500` calculations.

I've been trying to find a good way to solve this, but am not having much luck, because I don't have a math background in the slightest, and the articles about the various techniques are very overwhelming to try and understand.

At first I found out about random projection, but it looks like it may not conserve distance/similarity when reducing the dimensions. Someone else also recommended principal component analysis, but I'm not sure how I would do that, or whether or not the 2 dimensional result would contain enough entropy considering the initial vector had 500 dimensions.

I've also toyed with the idea of just saving all NxN pairs, but the resulting database table would require terabytes of data for 1,000,000 users. Not impossible, but the real problem comes in when you have to update 1,000,000 rows when the user changes their rating on something. At that point the insertion speed is too slow to be worth the selection speed being instantaneous.

Does anyone have any ideas or insight? Is this problem just intractable?

Comment: This is called clustering. It requires quite a bit of mathematics. So dive in, or don't bother. You can't expect to get this stuff without knowing the math,

Comment: I'm willing to put the work in, I just need to know exactly what I need to study.

Comment: Do you know linear algebra? Statistics? Basic probability?

Comment: Just the very basics in each. One college class for each.

Comment: What articles overwhelmed you

Comment: The technical name for this problem is "k nearest neighbor classification"

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. If someone tells me exactly what I need to do (that is, given this specific use-case I would be best served with _this_ exact solution), then I'll be able to hopefully understand it and apply it if I put in a week or so of effort. But I do not have the background to peruse the literature and determine the best solution. I need someone to tell me which solution would be ideal given the constraints I have presented, and then I can dedicate myself to understanding that solution and applying it.

Comment: If that's what you want, I don't think this is the right place to ask the question. I think you'll get a pretty good understanding of the tools you can use by reading up on k nearest neighbors. I don't think we can do much more than that for you.

Comment: Is this a better question for stackoverflow then? I thought someone here might be able to recommend a specific k nearest neighbor algorithm that would be ideal in this use-case.

Comment: To be more precise, it's not really possible for me to give you a definitive answer as to which particular variant of clustering is best for you, since I don't know the exact details. What norm do you want to optimize? Over what sort of space? How disjoint is the data? Etc

Comment: You won't get much luck there either. The question, in the form it is in, is not answerable.

Comment: Well, hopefully some others disagree then. Not sure where else I can ask this.

Comment: Good luck on that. I don't think that'll happen but best of wishes. I still am of the opinion that you seem scared to dive in to actually understand the meat and potatoes of what's going on.

Comment: I mean, I've been trying to solve this for weeks, so I'm not sure how you could surmise that. It's just very difficult for someone without a math background to understand and implement.

Comment: You can't convince me that articles like [these](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/introduction-k-neighbours-algorithm-clustering/) are too hard to digest. Please don't use your lack of a math background as an excuse. We all started from zero at some point. And, you claim to have taken at least a single course in all of the requisite fields. Even the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) is pretty basic.

Comment: It's not necessarily difficult if I know exactly what to study. If that article was "the true solution" that would work for this use-case, then I could really study it and implement it. But it doesn't seem like it's that easy. I've asked this to other people and they say the solution is tricky. It's not as simple as just performing a naive KNN. It needs to be fast and indexable in a database. Apparently once you pass a certain number of dimensions certain algorithms break down and start becoming less useful.

Comment: I think I'm done here after this, but you have to understand that it is not our problem to figure out the best solution to your business problems here. We aren't getting paid for this, you (presumably) are. Figuring out the solution to that is why you are working on the project, not us.

Comment: I'm not getting paid either. I'm just coding this on my own time. And I think this problem is general enough such that the solution would be useful for many people.

Comment: Please take a look at the other questions here on the site. Good questions tend to involve the users making more of an effort in understanding their field of study and what they want, not a "tell me what to do"

Comment: No, it is not. K-nearest neighbors might be, but not a problem where it needs to meet your specs.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can say I'm not putting in an effort when I've spent weeks on this trying to figure it out. I even tried out various random projection algorithms earlier without any luck. I noted the prior work I've done in the original post. And this problem _is_ rather general. It's simply the question of how to efficiently implement KNN with high-dimensional datasets and preserve distance. I just mentioned the Netflix example because I think better when I have concrete examples..

Comment: The netflix example isn't a problem, in fact, it's probably the reason this question is even somewhat answerable. But, the work you are referencing, what exact algorithms did you try? Were you trying them for a reason, or just trying out every one you see? What distance metric are you using? How sparse is the dataset? How many clusters do you expect? These are the kinds of questions you should be asking yourself. Anyways, I do need to get work done, so I would appreciate not getting pinged! Good talking to you, hopefully you find someone who has what you want.

Comment: I think I answered most of those questions in the original post. I tried random projection (and locality sensitive hashing), along with the bruteforce approach. I also tried using the CUBE postgres extension for indexing Euclidean distances (only works up to 100 dimensions unfortunately). I tried random projection out because I was researching this problem and others recommended its use for dimension reduction of large vectors and that they retained distances. With regard to sparsity and clusters, I mentioned in the OP that most people will rate most of the shows.

Comment: I mean level of clustering among data. Do people cleanly fall into clusters? Or is it a giant mush? Given person $A$ and $B$ that agree on item $x$, what is the probability they agree on $y$. That is what clustering means.

Comment: Well, that's one of the things I'm hoping to find out with this solution. I don't have that answer yet because I just have sample data at the moment.

Comment: I hope you understand that when I say effort, I mean mathematically, not from implementation's perspective. Anyways, it's quite obvious that you are not understanding what I mean by effort, so my time here is not helpful.

Comment: Okay well I'm sorry you feel that way. I'm not sure how I can put more effort into this considering I've been researching it and working on it every day for weeks now.. I'm just not nearly as mathematically minded so it's much harder for me to make progress.